# difference between get('doctrine'); and getDoctrine();

Tags: symfony, service, doctrine-orm, entity

In Symfony, I found three ways for accessing doctrine service and entity manager as follow:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();

$em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
```

Can anyone kindly explain their differences please and explain when should we use which of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first one is only available when extending the base controller. It's a shortcut to doing `$this->get('doctrine')`, as you can see [in the source](https://github.com/symfony/FrameworkBundle/blob/master/Controller/Controller.php#L278-292):

```
public function getDoctrine()
{
    if (!$this->container->has('doctrine')) {
        throw new \LogicException('The DoctrineBundle is not registered in your application.');
    }

    return $this->container->get('doctrine');
}
```

`$this->get('doctrine')` is also only available in controllers. `get` is also defined in the base controller and is a shortcut for `$this->container->get()`:

```
public function get($id)
{
    return $this->container->get($id);
}
```

`$this->container->get('doctrine')` is the fully written form of getting the doctrine registry.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->get('doctrine')  its the method to use services,
```

And in symfony you have shortcutes to call this service `$this->getDoctrine(`)